# reload data from firebase after updating object (row) using alert action

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I have a tableView which loads "tasks" in each row from firebase. after clicking on the row (a certain task), i've created an alert that asks if the task is completed. When the user presses "Yes" he needs to go back to the tableView, and that certain tasks shouldn't be there (as it moved from "tasks in progress" to "Completed tasks".
I've managed to update the task's status in firebase right after clicking "OK" but i cant manage to reload the data.. When the alert is dismissed, i still see that certain task in the tableView..

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let task = tasksInProgress[indexPath.row]
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "TASK STATUS",
                                  message: "Did you finished the task \(task.taskName)?",
                                  preferredStyle: .alert)

   alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes",
                                 style: .default,
                                 handler: { action in
    //    let taskName = self.tasksInProgress[indexPath.row].taskName
        Firebase.shared.updateDataBase(name: task.taskName)
        print(self.tasksInProgress.count)
    }))

   alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "no", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
   tasksInProgressTable.reloadData()
   self.present(alert,animated: true)
    }
```

Does anyone know where i should place the reloadData method? I tried to put it all over, including the completion block..

Comment: Most likely `updateDataBase` works asynchronously. Add a completion handler to get informed when the update is finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the update doesn't work inside the completion of the alertaction , then `updateDataBase` is asynchronous

Use `setvalue` of firebase is asynchronous

```
func updateDataBase(_ vv:String,completion:@escaping(()->()))    
    ref.setValue(<##>) { (error, ref) -> Void in
       completion()
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Sh_Khan. Thanks very much for your answer!

So, just updating my method to this - 

func updateDataBase(name:String, completion: () -> () ) {
        
db.collection("Tasks").document(name).updateData(["isCompleted" : true]) {err in
     if let err = err {
         print("there is an error. type: \(err)")
          }
            else {
                print("documet updated")
            }
        }
completion()
}

and then add this in the VC -
Firebase.shared.updateDataBase(name: task.taskName) {
self.tasksInProgressTable.reloadData()
}
This will do it?
Thanks again!